# How to copy files from a virtual machine to a local machine?

Tags: virtualbox, file-transfer

I have a virtual machine on Virtualbox with Ubuntu 15.04 (Command Line Interface only) and I want to copy files from the virtual machine to the host. As I have only CLI, I cannot use shared folders.

I have tried to access my USB drive from Virtualbox but it didn't help (I had to format hard drive after connecting to windows).

Is there any way to copy files from Ubuntu 15.04 (Virtual machine) to Windows 7 or USB drive?

---

My answer:
I marked one answer as good, but I managed to solve my problem before it. I created two python programs. one send file, second receiving file.

If someone need this program here is code: (in both change xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for IP of fileServer)

fileServer.py (on computer that you want to recieve files):

```
import socket
print('File server V 1.0 by vakus')
serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind(('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 9999))
serv.listen(1)
conn, addr = serv.accept()
print('Incoming Connection. Please write password:')
pas = bytes(input(), 'UTF-8')
conpass = conn.recv(1024)
if conpass != pas:
    print('Passwords are not the same. closing connection')
    conn.sendall(bytes('Passwords are not the same.', 'UTF-8'))
    conn.close()
    exit()
else:
    print('Passwords are the same.')
    conn.sendall(bytes('Passwords are the same.', 'UTF-8'))
filename = conn.recv(1024)
file = ""
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    file += data.decode('UTF-8')
    print(data.decode('UTF-8'), end='')
print('Close connection')
conn.close()
print('Creating file...')
try:
    import os
    os.mkdir('recv')
    del os
except:
    pass
f = open('recv/' + filename.decode("UTF-8"), 'w')
f.write(file)
f.close()
```

fileTransmiter.py (on computer that send file):

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 9999))
sock.sendall(bytes(input('Password: '), 'UTF-8'))
answer = sock.recv(1024)
print(answer)
if answer == bytes("Passwords are not the same.", 'UTF-8'):
    exit()
filename = input('File to send: ')
f = open(filename)
sock.sendall(bytes(filename, 'UTF-8'))
for x in f.readlines():
    print(x)
    sock.sendall(bytes(x, 'UTF-8'))
sock.sendall(bytes('', 'UTF-8'))
sock.close()
print('Connection closed.')
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up an SSH-server on the virtual machine and then using SFTP (with a client like FileZilla) to connect to the virtual machine from the host machine?

Comment: @up I did not but I would like to not install new packages (trying to keep ubuntu as smaller as possible)

Comment: Isn't SSH installed by default? If it is, it shouldn't be necessary to install additional packages.

Comment: It is installed but I have no idea how to setup ssh server and I cannot found anything that would help me with it

Comment: Added an answer with how to set up your SSH server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an SSH-server, try the following to set it up. I'm assuming your virtual machine doesn't need much security, as these instructions will open up root SSH logins for your guest machine. You could revert these changes when you're done.

I'm assuming the `openssh` server has already been installed.

- Open up your openssh configuration file with your favourite text editor. If you're using `vim` for example:

  ```
  sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  ```
- Add to the bottom or make sure the lines below aren't commented out. If you don't use `root` but another user, ignore the first two lines:

  ```
  PermitRootLogin without-password
  PermitRootLogin yes
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  ```
- Save the new configuration file.
- Restart the SSH server:

  ```
  sudo restart ssh
  ```

Then simply connect to your guest machine using an SFTP client like FileZilla. Just enter the IP address, the details of your root (or other) user into the GUI and connect.

Comment: Thanks for the information about setting up ssh server, but I still have one more question. When I try to connect with FilleZilla its says `fzSftp started, protocol_version=2` and `connection closed after 20 seconds of inactivity`(or something like that I'm using Polish version) and try to connect again. Also Im not sure does IP is right. I used one from `arp -an`

Comment: Get the IP by executing ifconfig from the command line on your virtual Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how, provided you have FileZilla:

1. in the `Quickconnect` box, enter `sftp://yourserver`, your username and password.
   [image: SFTP 1]
2. Hit connect
   [image: SFTP 2]
   You will get a SSH warning stating that you don't have that host key cached. Optionally click `Always trust this host, add this key to the cache`
   [image: SFTP 3]
3. Download those files!
   [image]